# Regular expression based detection

Tags: java, regex

I need to identify a pattern in given text (string), and I'm looking for a regex for the same. Using a Regex is preferable due to the framework I'm working in.

For instance, consider the text --

```
Problem:
<<<  empty line(s) >>>>
Reason:
here goes some multi-line reasoning...
...
...
```

As you can see there is "no text (empty line(s)) **after** `Problem:` and **before** `Reason:` ".

I need to be able to identify this pattern from the text given to me, using a regex.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Identify what? Please clarify your question

Comment: Actually I would not use an regular expression here but just check whether the read line was empty. If you insist on using a regexp, you are probably looking for \s which will match all whitespaces (including line-breaks).

Comment: Please check the question now (edited)

Comment: Why do you need to do it using a regex?

Comment: It's a limitation in the framework I'm working with. I understand there are better ways out though.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is off topic. Please explain or remove the regex tag from the forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest regex would be

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Problem:\\s+Reason:");
```

which finds the text `Problem:`, followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by the text `Reason:`.

If you want to make sure that there are at least two linebreaks between the two texts, you could also do

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Problem:[ \t]*\r?\n[ \t]*\r?\nReason:");
```

but that's probably not necessary.